# SceneKit: equivalent of SCNVector3(0, 0, 0) in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, swift, scenekit

The equivalent of this code in Swift:

```
startNode.scale = SCNVector3(1/100.0, 1/100.0, 1/100.0)
```

is:

```
[startNode setScale: SCNVector3Make(1/100.0, 1/100.0, 1/100.0)];
```

in Objective-C.

It seems strange that `SCNVector3` should be replaced by `SCNVector3Make`. Why is this?

Thanks!

Comment: So SCNVector3 and SCNVector3Make are strictly equivalent in Swift ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can** use `SCNVector3Make(x, y, z)` and `SCNVector3(x, y, z)` in Swift.

The latter is, indeed, strange in semantics, but they are **identical**.

Comment: Why is it strange? It follows all naming standards of conversion between C function API to Swift API.

Comment: @user28434 Check out `CGPoint`'s or `CGRect`'s initializer; they all have external parameter names, unlike `SCNVector3(x, y, z)`.

Comment: Indeed. Although, `SCNVector3` has Swift initializer with parameter names too for `Float`. But I think OP is wondering why `SCNVector3` is `SCNVector3Make` in Objective C, not why there're no paramter names.

Answer (score 1):

Both are same, only names are different and all because difference naming conventions in Apple C/ObjC frameworks and Swift code.

---

It would be better to show how it works on example:

Suppose we're creating framework `SomeFramework` (`SF` would be then namespace prefix) and in said framework we will have type `Example`, with prefix it would be `SFExample`.

Naming convention for C says that constructor for our type `SFExample` should be called `SFExampleMake`.

Naming convention for Swift says that constuctor should be `SFExample.init`, which can be called as `SFExample(…)`.

And when you're importing ObjC/C frameworks in your Swift project there's namecast behind the scene that turns `SFExampleMake` to `SFExample.init` or `SCNVector3Make` to `SCNVector3.init`.